# FOSRest gives fatal error in symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony

i am trying to install FOSRest & FOSRestBundle

initially , i have specified following settings in the `deps`

```
[FOSRest]
    git=git://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRest.git
    target=fos/FOS/Rest


[FOSRestBundle]
    git=git://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle.git
    target=bundles/FOS/RestBundle
```

*But that cause me into following error* when i access `http://localhost/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/`

> Fatal error: Declaration of
>   FOS\RestBundle\Routing\Loader\RestRouteLoader::setResolver() must be
>   compatible with that of
>   Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\LoaderInterface::setResolver() in
>   /home/logicase/public_html/Symfony/vendor/bundles/FOS/RestBundle/Routing/Loader/RestRouteLoader.php
>   on line 29

After that i tried following setting to make to the `master branch` and above error remains the same

```
[FOSRest]
    git=git://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRest.git
    target=fos/FOS/Rest
    version=origin/2.0

[FOSRestBundle]
    git=git://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle.git
    target=bundles/FOS/RestBundle
    version=origin/2.0
```

and now when i run `php ./bin/vendors install`

i get following message in console.

> > Installing/Updating FOSRest 5eb800bd63ba84e5fc7028386cb66373bc3efafc fatal: ambiguous argument 'origin/2.0': unknown revision or path not
>
> in the working tree. Use '--' to separate paths from revisions
>
> > Installing/Updating FOSRestBundle c11ab9d990a1e0e979b1c8ab72cc9793b4b2dcb5 fatal: ambiguous argument
> >     'origin/2.0': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried following settings for FOSRest which solved my problem for symfony 2

```
[FOSRest]
    git=git://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRest.git
    target=fos/FOS/Rest
    version=origin/0.6

[FOSRestBundle]
    git=git://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle.git
    target=bundles/FOS/RestBundle
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, there is no 2.0 branch : https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/branches https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRest/branches The installation documentation does not talk about it. You should just remove the version lines.

Comment: I have removed and reinstalled the vendors but still getting the same error of compatibility when i hit the http://localhost/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/ url